# How to create new columns in pandas dataframe using column values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in Python with a pandas DataFrame similar to:

```
REQUESET_ID | DESCR | TEST | TEST_DESC | RESULT |
         1  |     1 |   T1 | TEST_1    |  2.0   |           
         1  |     2 |   T2 | TEST_2    |  92.0  |                       
         2  |     1 |   T1 | TEST_1    |  8.0   |
         3  |     3 |   T3 | TEST_3    |  12.0  |
         3  |     4 |   T4 | TEST_4    |  45.0  |
```

What I want is a final dataframe like this:

```
 REQUESET_ID | DESCR_1 | TEST_1 | TEST_DESC_1 | RESULT_1 | DESCR_2 | TEST_2 | TEST_DESC_2 | RESULT_2 |
          1  |       1 |     T1 |   TEST_1    |  2.0     |       2 |   T2   |   TEST_2    |  92.0    | 
          2  |       1 |     T1 |   TEST_1    |  8.0     |   NaN   |  NaN   |     NaN     | Nan      |  
          3  |       3 |     T3 |    TEST_3   |  12.0    |       4 |   T4   |   TEST_4    |  45.0    |
```

How I should implement that as a method working with DataFrames. I understand that if I try to do it with a merge instead of having 4x2 columns added beacuse the value_counts method of the REQUEST_ID will return 2, will add the 4 columns for each entry in the request column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a new column with cumcount, then do `stack` + `unstack`

```
s=df.assign(col=(df.groupby('REQUESET_ID').cumcount()+1).astype(str)).\
       set_index(['REQUESET_ID','col']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s
             DESCR_1  RESULT_1 TEST_1  ... RESULT_2  TEST_2  TEST_DESC_2
REQUESET_ID                            ...                              
1                1.0       2.0     T1  ...     92.0      T2       TEST_2
2                1.0       8.0     T1  ...      NaN     NaN          NaN
3                3.0      12.0     T3  ...     45.0      T4       TEST_4
[3 rows x 8 columns]
```